# How to handle Nested 'LIST' with 'label' of each 'list-item'

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xquery, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

In the below example we are trying to handle Nested 'LIST' with 'label' of each 'list-item':

Label Example:

style="ListNum1" then a.,b.,c., ... etc.
style="ListNum2" then (1),(2),(3), ... etc.
style="ListNum3" then (a),(b),(c), ... etc.

Can anyone help.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<list-item style="ListNum1"><p content-type="new">Your client may (<styled-content style="stat" style-type="Stat-Cal">Prob C &#x00a7;13659</styled-content>) because:</p></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum2"><p content-type="new">For later income tax purposes</p></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum3"><p content-type="new">Documents a &#x201c;stepped-up basis&#x201d; (<italic>i.e.,</italic> fair.</p></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum3"><p content-type="new">Provides evidence for your client.</p></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum2"><p content-type="new">If you or your <bold>client</bold>.</p></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum1"><p content-type="new">If transfer <italic>unincorporated business</italic> appraisal. <styled-content style="stat" style-type="Stat-Cal">Prob C &#x00a7;13658</styled-content>.</p></list-item>
</body>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<list type="ListNum1">
<list-item style="ListNum1"><label>a.</label><p content-type="new">Your client may (<styled-content style="stat" style-type="Stat-Cal">Prob C &#x00a7;13659</styled-content>) because:</p></list-item>
<list type="ListNum2">
<list-item style="ListNum2"><label>(1)</label><p content-type="new">For later income tax purposes</p>
<list type="ListNum3">
<list-item style="ListNum3"><label>(a)</label><p content-type="new">Documents a &#x201c;stepped-up basis&#x201d; (<italic>i.e.,</italic> fair.</p></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum3"><label>(b)</label><p content-type="new">Provides evidence for your client.</p></list-item>
</list></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum2"><label>(2)</label><p content-type="new">If you or your <bold>client</bold>.</p></list-item>
</list></list-item>
<list-item style="ListNum1"><label>b.</label><p content-type="new">If transfer <italic>unincorporated business</italic> appraisal. <styled-content style="stat" style-type="Stat-Cal">Prob C &#x00a7;13658</styled-content>.</p></list-item>
</list>
</body>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list-item[@style='ListNum1']">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::list-item[@style='ListNum1']])">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<list list-type="ListNum1">]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[1][self::list-item[@style='ListNum1']])">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</list>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list-item[@style='ListNum2']">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::list-item[@style='ListNum2']])">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<list list-type="ListNum2">]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[1][self::list-item[@style='ListNum2']])">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</list>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list-item[@style='ListNum3']">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::list-item[@style='ListNum3']])">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<list list-type="ListNum3">]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[1][self::list-item[@style='ListNum3']])">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</list>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference URL #** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMoZ/1

Comment: Use a recursive function using `for-each-group group-starting-with="list-item[@style = 'ListNum' + $level]"` where `level` is an integer parameter of the function.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - Thank you, but here levels are diffirent and I'm unable to reach out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive grouping is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="format-map" as="map(xs:integer, xs:string)"
    select="map { 1 : 'a', 2 : '1', 3 : 'A' }"/>
    
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
      <xsl:param name="items" as="element(list-item)*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <list type="ListNum{$level}">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$items" group-starting-with="list-item[@style = 'ListNum' || $level]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <label>{format-integer(position(), $format-map($level))}</label>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), mf:group(tail(current-group()), $level + 1)"/>
                </xsl:copy>  
            </xsl:for-each-group>  
          </list>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(list-item, 1)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4v4

For the label formatting details, perhaps extend it as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="format-map" as="map(xs:integer, xs:string)"
    select="map { 1 : 'a', 2 : '1', 3 : 'a' }"/>
    
  <xsl:function name="mf:format" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="number" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:variable name="formatted-number"
        select="format-integer($number, $format-map($level))"/>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="if ($level = 1)
                then  $formatted-number || '.'
                else  '(' || $formatted-number || ')'"/>
  </xsl:function>
    
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
      <xsl:param name="items" as="element(list-item)*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <list type="ListNum{$level}">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$items" group-starting-with="list-item[@style = 'ListNum' || $level]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <label>{mf:format(position(), $level)}</label>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), mf:group(tail(current-group()), $level + 1)"/>
                </xsl:copy>  
            </xsl:for-each-group>  
          </list>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(list-item, 1)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4v4/1

Comment: Thank you Martin, It could other element also after the '<body>' element or before '</body>' element. along with the list

Comment: @Umaima, well, don't complicate the requirements in a comment to an answer. If you have more complex XML input structures and can't improve the suggested code to cope with them then consider to ask a new question where you more precisely describe the input structures you can have and how you want to map them to the corresponding output.